# How to read SharePoint Excel file from Python Script in PowerBi?

Tags: python, powerbi

I created a link for the text file (Shared to to be able to edit by anyone with link within the Org) and then tried the below code as Python script in Power BI. I get the following error.

PLease note that other Local shared drive files do work with the above method

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('https://company.sharepoint.com/:t:/s/NARenoLogEng/EY4OduNALeZMkiYKGphrtekB99wUdAMunzODo09YVV-oNw?e=Brf5I9', sep="}")
```

[image]

Comment: If you use a python script rather than the built in Excel or SharePoint connector you will have to use the personal gateway if you deploy it to the service.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to get a method to authenticate against SharePoint Online. Here is how I do it.

1. Download sp-rest-proxy from npm:

   https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-rest-proxy

**Here is a quick start on how I spin mine:** https://github.com/zergioz/spdev

2. Once you have the proxy authenticating; then, you can call the CSV file directly over the localhost:3000

   data = pd.read_csv('https://localhost:3000/path-to-file/to/load.xls', sep="}")

***The proxy will take care of authentication and fetching the file. The rest should be the same as normal.***

Comment: Let me try that...Thanks for responding

Comment: were you able to implement sp-rest-proxy?

Comment: Do I download sp-rest-proxy  through the Python CMD screen?

Comment: No. Do the following: 
# git clone https://github.com/zergioz/spdev.git
# cd spdev
# npm start 
# npm run sprestproxy

this should work on linux, windows, or mac